# How is XP awarded for combat?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

What's the formula for how XP is awarded for combat in Fallout: New Vegas? [The Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_Points) seems not to have it.

Comment: Piqued my curiosity. Trying to figure this out. I note that the page for [NV deathclaws](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) lists 50 xp as a reward for killing them. Seems like that might get modified by things, or maybe you just get static xp for each enemy type. Can't recall.

Comment: http://geck.bethsoft.com/index.php?title=Experience_Settings implies that each enemy gives a set amount of experience based on level. I'm not going to have an opportunity to test in New Vegas any time soon, but if someone could check if they get exactly 50xp for killing a death claw, that could lead to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each enemy has an assigned experience value. Every instance of the enemy you kill awards the same experience. Any experience modifiers, such as Fast Learner or Skilled, are applied afterwards multiplicatively.

For example, say you have a 10% bonus to exp, and a -10% penalty to exp, and you kill an enemy that gives you 100 exp points. You will always get 99 exp from that kill, regardless of it you increase by 10% then decrease by 10% of the new value or decrease by 10% then increase by 10% of the new value.